# Laravel gulp missing css source maps files

Tags: laravel, gulp, source-maps, laravel-elixir

CSS source maps are not generating. Whereas JS source maps are generating well without any error. My laravel version is `5.1`

I also tried this code below. Even though it's not working

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;
```

gulpfile.js

```
/**
 * Global CSS MIX
 */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "user/common.css",
        "user/custom.css",
        "user/font-awesome.min.css",
    ], 'public/assets/css/builds/global.css');
});

/**
 * Global JS MIX
 */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "angular/angular.min.js",
        "angular/angular-animate.js",
        "angular/angular-sanitize.min.js",
        "user/chat.js"
    ], 'public/assets/js/builds/global.js');
});
```

Directory structure

```
resources/
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   └── user
│   │       ├── common.css
│   │       ├── custom.css
│   │       ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   ├── js
│   │   └── angular
│   │       ├── angular.min.js
│   │       ├── angular-animate.js
│   │       ├── angular-sanitize.min.js
│   │   └── user
│   │       ├── chat.js
```

Comment: Please specify _what_ kind of problem you are experiencing.

Comment: CSS source maps are not generating

Comment: Could you run `npm list` and check which version of elixir is currently installed? Because as [stated in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#css-source-maps) source maps are generated by default within Elixir that was shipped with Larvel 5.1.

Comment: @Kovah laravel-elixir@3.4.3

Comment: try to remove node_modules directory and run npm install again

Comment: @bhill77 nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where is the problem. but upgrade to `laravel-elixir@^4.0.0` fix similar problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **sourceMaps()**?

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
            "user/common.css",
            "user/custom.css",
            "user/font-awesome.min.css",
        ], 'public/assets/css/builds/global.css')
        .sourceMaps();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes i tried But its not working. Error in the console "TypeError: mix.styles(...).sourceMaps is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your gulpfile.js you can add this:

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false; //for live version
// elixir.config.sourcemaps = true; //for dev version
```

Not sure if it will fix your specific problem, but on a couple of projects where I had the same error this helped.
(note laravel 5.0 - 5.2 max)